# Keyboard avoidance worked for UITexField - Not now in iOS 14

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

On an existing project with many many subclassed `UITextFields`, `UITextViews` and other text-based input subclasses  move a UIScroll (`self.view`) view up nicely for keyboard avoidance.

Since iOS 14 `UITextField` does not move the `UIScrollView` up for keyboard avoidance, everything else inc `UITextView`, continues to work fine however `UITextField` does not.  No changes to code or delegates have been made

```
   - (void)scrollToField:(id)field
{
  
    
        if (field != nil && [field isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
           
            UIView *control = (UIView *)field;
            CGFloat y = control.frame.origin.y - 90.0f;
            [self.view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (y < 0 ? 0 : y)) animated:YES];
    
        }
    }
```

The issue appears to be `UIView *control = (UIView *)field;`.  I take it UITextField is no longer a class of UIView? On this assumption [`UIView class]` & `UIView *control = (UIView *)field;` were all changed to `UITextField`.  Still the view does not move up as before.

```
   - (void)scrollToField:(id)field
{
  
    
        if (field != nil && [field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
           
            UITextField *control = (UITextField *)field;
            CGFloat y = control.frame.origin.y - 90.0f;
            [self.view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (y < 0 ? 0 : y)) animated:YES];
    
        }
    }
```

**In summary, the questions are:**

What is `UITextField` a class of in iOS 14?

How can I restore the functionality of moving my scrollview for `UITextField` prior to iOS 14

Comment: Your best bet to get help with this is to create a [mre]. Make it as simple as possible, showing just this issue, and post the code (somewhere such as GitHub).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this, an offset of -90.0f placed the `UITextfield` slightly under the navigation bar which prevented the scrolling.  Simply adjusting this to -100.0f gives a gap between the `UITextField` and Nav Bar and allows the scrolling behaviour as before